# Display none if image alt tag is:

Tags: image, shopify, alt

Is it possible to hide an image with a specific alt tag?

I'm using shopify and have a 360 gif that I want to use on mouseover on categorie (collection) pages, but I don't want the thumbnail on the product page. You can give images alt text, wondering if I use the alt tag "gif" on those images, if there is a way to hide them from appearing as a thumbnail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `alt` attribute to check whether it equal to **gif**. If so, skip them.

```
{%- for media in product.media -%}
  {%- unless media.alt == "gif" -%}
    ...
  {%- endunless -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```